# Eigen Vector4d as function argument?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am attempting to pass an Eigen::Vector4d into an function like this:

```
  Matrix3d quat2DCM(Vector4d quat)
  {
    quat = quat;
    return Matrix3d::Identity();
    //nevemind the guts of this function, that'l come after this works
  }
```

the VC++2005 compiler is giving me the following error:

> error C2719: 'quat': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned

Which does not happen for Eigen::Vector3d objects as arguments.  I have noticed that in some online discussion that the Vector4d class is particularly picky about it's alignment, moreso than the other canned typedefs.  When using the Vector4d in a class, I found it necessary to use the macro `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` which overrides the `new` Is there a similar workaround for passing them s arguments?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Eigen's doccumentation, passing fixed sized eigen objects can "[be illegal or make your program crash](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicPassingByValue.html)." This is because the alignment modifiers Eigen uses are not respected when the objects are passed by value. You should change your function so that it takes a `const` reference instead.

```
Matrix3d quat2DCM(const Vector4d& quat)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think I'd read that once but it hadn't sunk in.  I'd better go check and see where I've done that with other types.   Thanks!